# Puppet read file content after a class

Tags: puppet

I am trying to read a file content after executing a class GetContentsAPI, basically this class GetContentsAPI will write into the file /etc/api/token.

```
class Main{
    require GetContentsAPI   
    file("/etc/api/token")
}
```

When I did the above steps, its says `Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find any files from /etc/api`. Not sure how to make sure the file is already created before trying to read.

Thanks James

Answer (score 2):

The `file()` function reads the contents of a file during catalog *building*.  You don't present any details of class `GetContentsApi`, but all of the standard puppet facilities that write to files (especially, but not limited to, `File` resources) write during catalog *application*.  Unless you've cooked up something highly customized, the `file()` function will always read before `GetContentsApi` writes.

Moreover, in a master / agent setup (which is the only kind supported in current Puppet), catalog building happens on the master, whereas catalog application happens on the target node, which is usually a different machine, so you're unlikely even to be able to read what was written during a previous catalog-building run.

Also, `file()` just returns the file contents as a string, so it's not very useful to call it without using the return value somehow.

It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, but from what I can see, you are not going in a fruitful direction.  Perhaps you should take a step back and ask a different question about that.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for you constructive advice, is there any way to read the file content after its created.

Comment: @JamesSapam, the whole catalog is built before any part of it is applied. Therefore, even if it is built and applied on the same machine, the the outcome of applying it cannot be read back to inform building it.  You could write a custom fact that informs the *next* catalog run about the contents resulting from the present run.  Alternatively, you can take enough control over the target file to know what you want to know about what it *will* contain before you actually update it.